# How to increase timeout for NFC-V?

Tags: android, nfc, iso-15693

In my NFC application I came across a command which appears to take more time to respond than the `transceive()` method allows. As result I get a **TagLost** exception.

There is the method `setTimeout(int timeout)` for `IsoDep` tags, but afaik not for `NfcV` tags.

Does anyone know whether there is a way to increase the timeout value for `NfcV` operations?

Comment: Update: I had a look at the NFC code in Android to see whether I can find a way to set the timeout, maybe via reflection. Howewer, I ended up at interfaces to native code, of which I did not find the source code. So far I tried that with online sources, but not by downloading the full Android code to see whether that specific part of the code would be included.

Comment: Update: I added a feature encancement request to Android ([link](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57291&q=nfc&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars)). Lets's see whether this results in a solution.

Comment: Have the same problem, anyone has found any solution?